# Performance of OpenTSDB

Tags: hadoop, hbase, time-series, database-performance, opentsdb

It takes 6 seconds to return json of 9000 datapoints.
I have approximately 10GB of Data in 12 metrics say x.open, x.close...

**Data Storage pattern:**
Metric : x.open
tagk : symbol
tagv : stringValue

Metric : x.close
tagk : symbol
tagv : stringValue

My **Configurations** are on Cluster Setup as follows

**Node 1**: (Real 16GB ActiveNN) JournalNode, Namenode, Zookeeper, RegionServer, HMaster, DFSZKFailoverController, TSD

**Node 2**: (VM 8GB StandbyNN) JournalNode, Namenode, Zookeeper, RegionServer

**Node 3**: (Real 16GB) Datanode, RegionServer, TSD

**Node 4**: (VM 4GB) JournalNode, Datanode, Zookeeper, RegionServer
the setup is for POC/ Dev not for production.

**Wideness of timestamp** is like, one datapoint each for a day for each symbol under easch metric from 1980 to today..
If the above statement is confusing ( My 12 metrics would get 3095 datapoints added everyday in a continuous run one for each symbol.)
**Cardinality** for tag values in current scenario is 3095+ symbols

**Query Sample:**
http://myIPADDRESS:4242/api/query?start=1980/01/01&end=2016/02/18&m=sum:stock.Open{symbol=IBM}&arrays=true

**Debugger Result:**
8.44sec;  datapoints retrieved 8859;  datasize: 55kb

Data writing speed is also slow, it takes 6.5 hours to write 2.2 million datapoints.
Am I wrong somewhere with Configurations or expecting much ?

Method for Writing:  Json objects via Http

Salting Enabled: Not yet

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/opentsdb/performance$20a$20question/opentsdb/Z9RVW5eoqDg/eT293PlrAwAJ

Answer (score 0):

too much data in one metric will cause performance down. The result may be 9000 data point but the raw data set may be too big.  The performance of retrieving 9000 data points from one million will be very different from retrieving 9000 data points from one billion.